# How to turn off Opera Mini "discover"/"top stories" news feed?

Tags: opera-mini

I installed Opera Mini and was surprised at how slow it was to open. I figured out this was because it was automatically filling the home page with "Yahoo"-style random news headlines.

I couldn't find any way to turn this off. Long-pressing on the panel of headlines didn't give any "remove" option, the "Customise" button at the bottom of the feed didn't allow turning off the feed even when I deselected every type of story, and the only relevant thing I could see in the settings menus (Advanced > Feeds) was already set to disabled.

Searching online, all I could find was people on Opera forums being snarky at anyone who didn't want this feature, or, guides for different versions of Opera that don't apply to Opera Mini. Some sources say it's impossible. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option under Settings, but it's tucked away under Advanced settings and the wording might not be intuitive to people unfamiliar with browser jargon:

- In the popup settings menu from the Opera icon in the bottom right, (or menu button if you have one), choose **Settings > Advanced > Start page content**
- Switch from **Default** to **Speed Dial only**

This turns off the news feed on the new tab home page.