# turn off opera news stories

Tags: opera-browser

I have never used Opera. Still, once a day or so I get a notification of some news headline. I don't have to open opera for this, it appears on my phone "dashboard" that lists all my apps and I can also see the notification from the screen that just shows the clock and text message notifications, etc. (Sorry I don't really know much mobile terminology).

Is this the same issue described here?
[How to turn off Opera Mini "discover"/"top stories" news feed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149864/how-to-turn-off-opera-mini-discover-top-stories-news-feed)
The person who posted that question seems to have a problem with the browser home page showing news stories.

I'm using Android 6.0.1, Security Patch Level Oct 1, 2016. My phone is a Blu Life One X2.

This feature is extremely irritating and I wonder who thought such an intrusive app was a good design decision.

Comment: From settings> sound notification> app notifications -enable block all and disable other two options - does that not get rid of the notifications?

Comment: I tried that before but then I made some other changes and whatever else I did must have turned the notifications back on. I just turned notifictions off again and I'll just wait to see if anything else happens by tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Also for lockscreen notifications settings> sound & notification >notification> when device is locked > choose options

Comment: If it doesn't solve your problem, please edit what you have tried into the question so that other solutions can be offered by readers

Comment: I use the Mini version of Opera which has the Setting to disable all such things and I'm sure that the bigger version of Opera has it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. **Turn off notifications**

Menu > Settings >  Advanced > Notifications > Turn Off Opera notifications

See screenshot:

[image: a]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Opera will display a message when

- New email, feed, or news items arrive
- Downloads are completed

So turning off these notificaions will help you get rid of annoying news, and I been pretty using this settings and no news items appear on notification bar.

2. **Patching the application**

There is also a patch developed by namok o95 which "disables recommended stories" but works at system level so you may need another application to apply the patch.

It may depend on your current opera mini versions but  I use  method 1.

Hope this helps